# Discord.js Level Roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, roles

```
 //level roles

var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "test");

if(xpfile[message.author.id].level == 1)message.member.guild.roles.add(role);
```

This is the code for the Level Roles from my XP System.
Can someone say me why it dosen't work?
There is no error, but the Bot don't add the Role.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Are you trying to add the role to the guild or to the user?

Comment: To the User. Not to the Server.

Comment: Have you logged within the if-statement to confirm it executes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the role to the user you need to do something like this:

```js
 //level roles

var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "test");

if(xpfile[message.author.id].level == 1)message.member.roles.add(role);
```

Removing the .guild as you do not need to access the guild of the message but only the member.